# Angular : timer broken by change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

My problem relies in these two lines of Angular code :

```
<div *ngIf="timer$ | async as timer"> {{timer}}</div>
<ng-katex-paragraph [paragraph]="formula"></ng-katex-paragraph>
```

[image]
The first line is a simple timer that refreshes every 100th second.
The second line is a third-party library ("ng-katex"), that displays a mathematical formula (from the string `formula`)

Issue : every time the timer refreshes, the formula is refreshed as well (like : re-generated), and it takes time. As a consequence the timer is slowed down.

If I had control over the Katex library, I would set changeDetectionStrategy to "onPush" inside it, but Katex is a third party library, so how could I force it to *not* refresh ?

Thanks for your help !
Here is a minimal repro : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vafchf

Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to wrap the formula component into a component of its own, and set its change detection strategy to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` like this:

```
// wrap the base component into an onpush.
@Component({
  selector: "my-formula",
  template: `<ng-katex-paragraph [paragraph]="paragraph">
             </ng-katex-paragraph>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyFormulaComponent {
  @Input("paragraph")
  paragraph: string = '';
}
```

and change your component html to use it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="timer$ | async as timer"> {{timer}}</div>
<my-formula [paragraph]="formula"></my-formula>
```

Don't forget to register the new component into your `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule , KatexModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, MyFormulaComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Needless to say, you will have to manage the push strategy yourself of the formulas, using `changeDectorRef`, see: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Glad that helped :)